# Yii2: Defining a REST API Parameter other than 'ID'

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to utilise the YII2 REST API (based in the Advanced Template) to create my own service.  I am currently using the following URL successfully to return me a single 'Article' record:

http://service/articles/view?id=1

I am now trying to copy this code so it works for another record type.  My new record has a primary key called '*key*' which I would like to search by.  Accordingly, I need to change the parameter name '*id*' to '*key*'.

Could someone please explain how to specify a parameter other than '**id**' on this URL?  Whenever I omit id as a parameter, I get a "*Bad request: Missing required parameters: id*".  I don't understand where this required parameter comes from and how to change or add to it.

Relevant classes look like:

```
class ArticleController extends ActiveController
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\modules\api\v1\resources\Article';
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items'
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'index' => [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
                'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
                'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'prepareDataProvider']
            ],
            'view' => [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
                'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
                'findModel' => [$this, 'findModel']
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction'
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function prepareDataProvider()
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider(array(
            'query' => Article::find()->published()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return array|null|\yii\db\ActiveRecord
     * @throws HttpException
     */
    public function findModel($id)
    {
        $model = Article::find()
            ->published()
            ->andWhere(['id' => (int) $id])
            ->one();
        if (!$model) {
            throw new HttpException(404);
        }
        return $model;
    }
}

class Article extends \common\models\Article implements Linkable
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return ['id', 'slug', 'category_id', 'title', 'body', 'published_at'];
    }

    public function extraFields()
    {
        return ['category'];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of links.
     *
     * @return array the links
     */
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return [
            Link::REL_SELF => Url::to(['article/view', 'id' => $this->id], true)
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Specification of the urlManager in 'frontend' folder structure is as follows:

```
<?php
return [
    'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=> [
        // Pages
        ['pattern'=>'page/<slug>', 'route'=>'page/view'],

        // Articles
        ['pattern'=>'article/index', 'route'=>'article/index'],
        ['pattern'=>'article/attachment-download', 'route'=>'article/attachment-download'],
        ['pattern'=>'article/<slug>', 'route'=>'article/view'],

        // Api
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'api/v1/article', 'only' => ['index', 'view', 'options']],
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'api/v1/user', 'only' => ['index', 'view', 'options']]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Check the ViewAction docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-viewaction.html#run()-detail, it needs to receive the `$id` parameter by default. What I would do is create a new action, let's say `view2`, and there add the functionality you need.

Comment: it looks like you are using different rules from what [default yii2 routing for REST](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) are usually implemented. could you also show your `urlManager` settings?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @gmc.  Would you know (or be able to refer me to the documentation) where the "id" value is configured if I create a new method as you suggest?

Comment: @Salem, I'm not sure where to find the urlManager settings (I'm a bit of a newbie).

Comment: you'll find it inside your configuration file. it is where your url `rules` are defined. you'll see it in the docs I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi @SalemOuerdani, I have added the content of the urlManager as found in the 'frontend' folder structure (there are a couple of instances, but I believe frontend is used for the API in the Advanced Template)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by adding rules to your urlmanager in the config documentation can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail)

Example:

```
'rules' => [
    [   'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'pluralize' => false,
        'controller' => [
            'yourController',
        ],
        'patterns' => [
            'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',
            'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
            'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view',
            'GET,HEAD {key}' => 'view',
            'POST' => 'create',
            'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
            '{id}' => 'options',
            'OPTIONS' => 'options',
            'PUT,PATCH {key}' => 'update',
        ],
         'tokens' => [
            '{id}' => '<id:\\d[\\d,]*>',
            '{type}' => '<type:\\w[\\w,]*>',
            '{key}' => '<key:\\w[\\w,]*>',
        ],
    ],
]
```

add the action mapping to yourController

```
class YourController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'your\model\Class';

    public function actions() {
        return array_merge(parent::actions(), [
            'view' => [
                'class' => \rest\your\ViewAction',
                'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and add the key param to your action

```
class ViewAction  extends \yii\rest\ViewAction {

    public function run($id = null, $key = null)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to do this

`GET your/{keyparam} -> wil resolve to yourController -> ViewAction`

Comment: Hi @Tim, could you please tell me the specific settings I need in my example to only accept "key" in the GET URL and not "id"?  I have tried numerous permutations of all these settings but can't figure out how to omit the 'id' parameter.  The documentation is unfortunately is not self-explanatory to me.  I've tried adding a pattern saying 'GET,HEAD {key}' =>'view' but this doesn't work.

Comment: @SimpleGuy apologies for my late response but I've updated my answer how to configure the controller and corresponding views hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the official way of doing this, but I have created an extra Action to deal with this situation.  It seems that the "id" parameter comes from Reflecting the "run" method call in the Action, so the only way I could use a different parameter called 'key' is by defining the function exactly like so:

```
class ExtraAction extends Action  // in yii/rest
{
    public function run($key)  // NOTE: The name 'key' is reflected and then becomes an expected parameter
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($key);

        if (!$model) {
            throw new HttpException(404);
        }
        return $model;
    }
}
```

Once this was done, I needed to change my actions() definition like so:

```
    'view' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\ExtraAction',
        'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
        'findModel' => [$this, 'findModel']
    ],
```

findModel($id) in the controller would then receive the 'key' parameter as defined in the GET URL (eg. api/v1/article?key=blah123).

I could then perform a find based on a different unique key that I had:

```
public function findModel($id)
{
    $model = Record::find()
    ->andWhere(['key_field' => $id])
    ->one();    
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way of doing it, but it does seem to work for this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just create the new method inside `ArticleController` as usual:

```
public function actionView2($your_desired_parameter) {
    $article = Article::find()->where(['your_desired_parameter'=>$your_desired_parameter]);
    if (!$article->exists()) 
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    return $article->one();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gmc, although do I need to also add a "view2" action in the Controller?  If so, what should my 'class' property be?  If I set this to 'ViewAction' it will again insist that I need to provide an id.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you do not need to add it there

Comment: Just adding 'actionView2' doesn't work, unfortunately ("Page not found").  I seem to need to add an action, but if I copy-and-paste the "view" action as "view2", I again need to provide an 'id' (even when using the code you mentioned).